# use variable from $get in query

Tags: php, sql, excel, variables

Have a php scripts that holds 2 functions.
In the first function the query is using the $get to fetch  time and date.
The second function is making im trying to  use the variable from the first function.

```
public function Execute( ) {


    if( $_GET['from'] && $_GET['to'] ){

        $from = $_GET['from'];
        $to = $_GET['to'];


       $query =  "SELECT * from historie_ordre where kode = ? AND time BETWEEN ? AND ? AND  order by time desc";
       $orders = DB::query( $query, $kode,  $from, $to )->fetchAll( DB::FETCH_ASSOC );


        Util::Debug( $orders  );
        $this->stats = $orders;

    }

    $this->kode = $kode;
    $this->from = $from;
    $this->to = $to;


}
```

second funstion:

```
     public function XLS(  ) {


 //trying to use this:
$from = intval($_GET['from']);
$to = intval($_GET['to']);
$kode = intval($_GET['kode']);



     $query =  "SELECT * from historie_ordre where kode = $kode AND time BETWEEN $from AND $to AND  order by time desc"; 

        $orders = DB::query( $query, $kode,  $from, $to )->fetchAll( DB::FETCH_ASSOC );


         $this->setTemplate( false );

         $oldreporting = error_reporting( 0 );

         require_once 'Spreadsheet/Excel/Writer.php';

// Creating a workbook
$workbook = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Writer();

// sending HTTP headers
$workbook->send('stabburet_stats.xls');

// Creating a worksheet
$worksheet =& $workbook->addWorksheet('My first worksheet');

// overskrift
//$worksheet->write(0, 0, 'Antall');
$worksheet->write(0, 1, 'kode');
$worksheet->write(0, 2, 'name');
$worksheet->write(0, 3, 'adress');


$i=1;
// for å få inn verdiane
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    $i++;
    //$worksheet->write($i, 0, $order['antall']);
    $worksheet->write($i, 1, $order['kode']);
    $worksheet->write($i, 2, utf8_decode( $order['name'] ) );
    $worksheet->write($i, 3, utf8_decode ($order['adress']) );


}        

// Sender fila
$workbook->close();
         error_reporting( $oldreporting );

      }



    }
```

The first function is working. second is only working with "hardcoding" the variables.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but in the first part you write `[...] where kode = ? [...]` where you in the second part write `[...] where kode = $kode [...]`, seems like the second part is not correct?

Comment: Why you stop using prepared statements in second function?

Comment: Yup, has nothing to do with $_GET.  You need to be consistent when programming.

Comment: the scripts holds a html who $to and $from are entered. when i try use the $ variable direct in the query is returns nothing.

Comment: @Slistryko that is because your query is trying to search for the words `$to` and `$from` rather than the value within them. You need to change the way you construct your query.

Answer (score 0):

It was pointed out to you in comments you need to be more careful and use the same techniques consistently.  I also don't believe that the first function *works*, because your query syntax in each place is wrong.

The problem at very least is that you have an incorrect SELECT syntax with a spurious AND at the end.  You also are using a column named time, which is a mysql reserved word.  That might also be a problem, that can be mitigated by using the `` `column name` `` syntax.

```
 $query =  "SELECT * 
            from historie_ordre 
            WHERE kode = $kode 
                AND time BETWEEN $from AND $to AND  
            order by time desc";
```

Needs to be:

```
  $query =  "SELECT * 
             FROM historie_ordre
             WHERE kode = ? 
             AND `time` BETWEEN ? AND ? 
             ORDER BY `time` DESC";
```

***Updated:***

Now that we have more information from you, the problem can also be traced to here:

```
$from = intval($_GET['from']);
$to = intval($_GET['to']);
$kode = intval($_GET['kode']);
```

The problem is that your from and to need to be strings in date format.  You are forcing them to be zeros by turning them into integers.  So again your query is not going to function.

```
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$kode = intval($_GET['kode']);
```

Comment: sorry for the spurious AND, the query is a bit longer originaly. Is it possible to use the variables in the query? then i try to use the ? in query its working if i define the variable as ex this in the top of function;  $from = '2017-06-01';
 $to = '2017-06-03'; (but then its hardcoded not from function 1)

Comment: trying to use the: $from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];
$kode = intval($_GET['kode']); in the second function to call the variables and use the ? in the query, but returns empty.

Comment: For this to work the format of the $from and $to variables need to be very specific:  yyyy-mm-dd, or as you hardcoded them.    Also, if you hardwire the variables as you did before, AND you use parameters  (?) in the query, does the query work?

Comment: it works if i hardcoding the variabels. like this: $from = '2017-06-01';
$to = '2017-06-15'; -and use ? using ? the query and not $

Comment: Ok, so you are entering the dates in your form in exactly that format?

Comment: form are the same, but witouth the quotes

Comment: Right at the top of the function do this:  var_dump($_GET);   What do you have there?

Comment: then i get the:Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE in /var/www/paga/sites/admin/views/order/ny.php on line 58 - in this line i have the:$kode = intval($_GET['kode']); if i put the var_dump($_GET) in the first function i have the same error even if this function is returning correct

Comment: Probably when you inserted code you deleted a ;  -check your code.

Comment: perhaps the second function are missing something. Before query i have this: public function XLS(  ) {
         
  
     $from = $_GET['from'];
                $to = $_GET['to'];

Comment: but in first function i have this before query : public function Execute( ) {
 
   
 
           
            
            if( $_GET['from'] && $_GET['to'] ){
                
                $from = $_GET['from'];
                $to = $_GET['to'];